# asp.net + private message system notification

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to build a private message inbox system in my asp.net app, using SQL Server to store the messages between users but one thing I am not sure how to achieve is this, for e.g facebook immediately notifies a user when he/she recieves a new message or notification through the action of another user as a red icon on its top navigation bar. I have read through some of the tutorials and guides and most of them requires some sort of polling to the database every few seconds. Can anyone shed some light on what is a good way to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used SignalR to do something similar to this in the past.  It can be installed via NuGet by Install-Package SignalR

Scott Hanselman has a great write up: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Also, [jabbr.net](http://jabbr.net/) is a fully functional example of what, I think, is pretty close to what you want to do.